# Fastest way to loop through this array in Javascript on Chrome 36

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a very big array which looks similar to this

```
var counts = ["gfdg 34243","jhfj 543554",....] //55268 elements long
```

this is my current  loop

```
var replace = "";
var scored = 0;
var qgram = "";
var score1 = 0;
var len = counts.length;

function score(pplaintext1) {
    qgram = pplaintext1;
    for (var x = 0; x < qgram.length; x++) {
        for (var a = 0, len = counts.length; a < len; a++) {
            if (qgram.substring(x, x + 4) === counts[a].substring(0, 4)) {
                replace = parseInt(counts[a].replace(/[^1-9]/g, ""));
                scored += Math.log(replace / len) * Math.LOG10E;
            } else {
                scored += Math.log(1 / len) * Math.LOG10E;
            }
        }
    }
    score1 = scored;
    scored = 0;
} //need to call the function 1000 times roughly
```

I have to loop through this array several times and my code is running slowly. My question is what the fastest way to loop through this array would be so I can save as much time as possible.

Comment: Define "very big": 10? 100? 1M? 1P elements?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy is telling you that unless this portion of the code is the one that actually slows down the program as a whole, you should not care about it and go for the obvious way.

Comment: Show use the code inside loop, there is probably a problem with performance. You could try with sorting array to get better results.

Comment: @user3184807: a "bottleneck" means something that slows down a process or activity.

Comment: so the first element seems like a key, and the number as an associated value. Are the keys unique ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `counts` array appears to be a list of unique strings and values associated with them.  Use an object instead, keyed on the unique strings, e.g.:

```
var counts = { gfdg: 34243, jhfj: 543554, ... };
```

This will *massively* improve the performance by removing the need for the `O(n)` inner loop by replacing it with an `O(1)` object key lookup.

Also, avoid divisions - `log(1 / n) = -log(n)` - and move loop invariants outside the loops.  Your `log(1/len) * Math.LOG10E` is actually a constant added in every pass, except that in the first `if` branch you also need to factor in `Math.log(replace)`, which in log math means adding it.

p.s. avoid using the outer scoped state variables for the score, too!  I *think* the below replicates your scoring algorithm correctly:

```
var len = Object.keys(counts).length;

function score(text) {
    var result = 0;
    var factor = -Math.log(len) * Math.LOG10E;

    for (var x = 0, n = text.length - 4; x < n; ++x) {
        var qgram = text.substring(x, x + 4);
        var replace = counts[qgram];
        if (replace) {
            result += Math.log(replace) + factor;
        } else {
            result += len * factor;  // once for each ngram
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @user3184807 because the object key lookup is `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`, _and_ because it avoids the need to use `substr` on the `count` values.

Comment: Because you don't need to substring the array value in the if clause everytime. Branch prediction will not be good when trying to analyse this array anyway, having it run computation on the values will slow it down more. The object is the way to go. (What Alnitak said)

Comment: @user3184807 I've realised there's a discrepancy in my algorithm compared to yours - in your code for each qgram in the original string you add the found score or your 1/n factor in the inner loop for *every* word in the `counts` list.  In mine I'm only adding `len * 1/n` if the qgram isn't found in the `counts` list at all, so if the qgram *is* found it's missing `factor * (len - 1) / n`

Comment: anyway... thanks for telling me about the object lookup it helped so much